# PHP Day of the Week used as conditional link

Tags: php

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796156/simulate-php-date-n-forward-and-backward-using-php/25796509#25796509) I was able to build forward/backward functionality based on the current day of the week using a href links.  I also wanted to be able to have a a href link for a specific day so you'll notice I added the `$link_7` for example and built a Sunday a href.  Here is where the crazyness comes in.  You'll Notice `$link_7` is Specified and is for Sunday but I have to make the actual href a `2` for Sunday.  Today is Friday so I think my routine is doing a +2 and throwing off the value.  What is the best way to circumvent this when going direct to a Day of the week?

```
if (array_key_exists('day', $_GET)) {
    $add_day = $_GET['day'];
} else {
    $add_day = 0;
}

$yesterday = $add_day - 1;
$tomorrow = $add_day + 1;

$link_yesterday = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=' . $yesterday ;
$link_tomorrow  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=' . $tomorrow ;

$link_7  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=7' ;
$link_1  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=1' ;
$link_2  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=2' ;
$link_3  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=3' ;
$link_4  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=4' ;
$link_5  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=5' ;
$link_6  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?day=6' ;

$display_day = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d") + $add_day, date("Y"));

$today = date('N', $display_day);
```

```php
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_yesterday;?>">See Yesterday</a>
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_tomorrow;?>">See Tomorrow</a> | 
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_2;?>">Sunday</a>        
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_3;?>">Monday</a>
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_4;?>">Tuesday</a>
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_5;?>">Wednesday</a>
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_6;?>">Thursday</a>
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_7;?>">Friday</a>
<a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $link_1;?>">Saturday</a>
```

```php
if( $today == 7) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Sunday</th>
<?php } elseif( $today == 1 ) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Monday</th>
<?php } elseif( $today == 2 ) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Tuesday</th>
<?php } elseif( $today == 3 ) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Wednesday</th>
<?php } elseif( $today == 4 ) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Thursday</th>
<?php } elseif( $today == 5 ) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Friday</th>
<?php } elseif( $today == 6 ) { ?>
<th class="WADAResultsTableHeader">Saturday</th>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What does it do?

Comment: Actually I updated the question.  I got it to work but still having strange behavior.

Comment: You should look into the DateTime class http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php That way can easily modify dates accurately

Comment: I'll check it out, I'm just so frustrated with the whole thing at this point...should have taken about 15 min. and I'm going on a few hours messing with this thing LOL

Comment: `date("d") + $add_day` could be the 34th of february... Use `DateTime` has @DavidJones said.

Comment: I will, still I need to figure out a way to circumvent the +1 -1 functionality when I send the day of the week directly.  Pretty sure that is what is throwing off the href and datetime won't fix that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So why do you give `?day=7` for Sunday ? It will always depends of the current day ! It indeed **has** to be `2`. It should be `$day='.(7 - date('N'))`